# Convert hh:mm:s to hh:mm:ss

Tags: bash, sorting, type-conversion

I'm trying to sort a two columns list, where the second column has time as hh:mm:s using sort -k2
e.g.

```
peer0 23:51:3
peer1 23:51:18
peer2 23:51:15
```

and I get

```
peer1 23:51:18

peer0 23:51:3

peer2 23:51:15
```

Most probably, one issue is the missing 0 before 3 for seconds.
Any idea how to add this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some implementations of `sort` (e.g. the one from GNU coreutils) offer version sort (`-V`), which would sort `1:3` before `1:30`.

```
sort -k2,2V
```

If your `sort` does not have this, numerically (`-n`) sort by the individual time components. If you had only the time, that would be `sort -t: -n`. But since you have whitespace-separated columns and colon-separated time components, you need a bit of pre- and post-processing to do so.

If your data does not contain `:` otherwise, you can use

```
< yourFile tr ' ' ':' | sort -t: -n -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 | sed 's/:/ /'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

data='23:51:3
23:51:18
23:51:15
'

echo "$data" | awk -F':' -v OFS=':' '{ if (length($3) == 1) $3="0"$3; print }' | sort -t: -k2
```

Comment: I don't think that you can use that. OP stated that the date was in the second column but didn't provide a sample of the input file

Comment: You are right, the answer is based only on the provided data.